# BIRT: Custom Highcharts Event Handlers

Tags: colors, highcharts, click, birt, designer

I am attempting to set a custom event handler in a BIRT report to change the color of a bar when I click on it. I am doing this in the JS theme editor as can be seen in the following screenshot:[image].

I have tried multiple ways of writing this, but as far as I can tell there is nothing wrong with the script, yet obviously the compiler thinks something is wrong. Can anyone shed some light on this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can catch click event on the point and call point.update() function.

```
plotOptions: {
        column: {
            point: {
                events: {
                    click:function(){
                        this.update({color:'red'});
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/etd9t0qx/1/